# Angular Error TS2554:Expected 0 arguments, but got x on piped operators

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an `Error TS2554: Expected 0 arguments, but got 4` in the pipe of the observable `getHappyDays()`

`getHappyDays()` Observable returns a  `Observable<HttpResponse<IHappyDays>> | Observable<HttpErrorResponse>` , I've included a stackblitze to better showcase the problem

```
 resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot):
    Observable<IHappyDays> | Observable<never> {

    return this.happyService.getHappyDays()
      .pipe(//=>error thrown here
        first(),
        mergeMap((res) => {
          return of(res.body)
        })
      )
  }
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3iujhb // in happy-resolver.service

Comment: Include all relevant information IN the question, not links. Information in links should only be supportive and not critical to explaining the problem precisely.

Comment: @user2864740 I have added extra code and explanation to the question

Comment: The stackblitz doesn't show the problem.

Comment: @Phix I've fixed the Stackblitze link to edit the app, it's on the happy-resolver.service file

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Frist, a semicolon is missing after the `pipe()`. The main problem is the union return type in `getHappyDays()`. It will work when you change it to `Observable<HttpResponse<IHappyDays> | HttpErrorResponse>` (see: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/3388).

Note regarding interface design: I wouldn't return `HttpErrorResponse` as a value since this obliviously is an error. Angular `HttpClient` documentation provides some guidelines how to deal with errors: https://angular.io/guide/http

Comment: Do you think I should rename the question to Union of Observable cannot have piped operators

Comment: Yes, might make sense, that others can find it easier.