# ngrx conditional api call

Tags: typescript, rxjs, ngrx

I have the following effect, in one case I want to login as admin, in the second as normal user.

```
  signIn$ = createEffect(() =>
    this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType(AuthActions.signInRequest),
      exhaustMap(({ variables, redirectTo, hasAdmin }) => hasAdmin ?  
        this.authService.signInAdmin(variables) : 
        this.authService.signIn(variables).pipe(
          map((response) => {
            //... AuthActions.signInSuccess(response.token)
          }),
          catchError(() => of(AuthActions.signInFailure()))
        )
      )
    )
  );
```

The response from the API is exactly the same, but I got

> Type 'Observable<FetchResult<SignInAdmin, Record<string, any>, Record<string, any>> | FetchResult<SignIn, Record<string, any>, Record<...>>>' is not assignable to type 'EffectResult'.
> Type 'Observable<FetchResult<SignInAdmin, Record<string, any>, Record<string, any>> | FetchResult<SignIn, Record<string, any>, Record<...>>>' is not assignable to type 'Observable'.
> Type 'FetchResult<SignInAdmin, Record<string, any>, Record<string, any>> | FetchResult<SignIn, Record<string, any>, Record<string, any>>' is not assignable to type 'Action'.

> Property 'type' is missing in type 'FetchResult<SignInAdmin, Record<string, any>, Record<string, any>>' but required in type 'Action'.ts(2322)
> models.d.ts(2, 5): 'type' is declared here.

> effect_creator.d.ts(42, 161): The expected type comes from the return type of this signature.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing a return value for the success case:
This should work (assuming the authService returns the same type of result for both login cases):

```
signIn$ = createEffect(() =>
    this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType(AuthActions.signInRequest),
      exhaustMap(({ variables, redirectTo, hasAdmin }) => hasAdmin ?  
        this.authService.signInAdmin(variables) : 
        this.authService.signIn(variables).pipe(
          map((response) => {
            //... AuthActions.signInSuccess(response.token)
          }),
          catchError(() => of(AuthActions.signInFailure()))
        )
      ),
      map(signInResult => AuthActions.signInSuccess({data: signInResult))
    )
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

for future reader, the problem is the same as this => [Angular Error TS2554:Expected 0 arguments, but got x on piped operators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54638867/angular-error-ts2554expected-0-arguments-but-got-x-on-piped-operators)

somehow, pipe is breaking and do not accept argument when the observable you pipe on has not exactly the same interface (even if 2 interface share the exact same properties)

so I fixed doing

```
      exhaustMap(({ variables, redirectTo, hasAdmin }) => {
        return ((hasAdmin
          ? this.authService.signInAdmin(variables)
          : this.authService.signIn(variables)) as Observable<
          FetchResult<SignInAdmin | SignIn>
        >).pipe(
```